# How to enter CSRF on ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax, csrf, csrf-protection

I have this code

```
    ---------- index.php ----------
    <script>
    function validLogin() {
    var email=$('#memail').val();
    var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var password=$('#mpass').val();
    var dataString = email='+ email + '&password='+ password;
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "processed.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(result){
                   var result=trim(result);
                   if(result=='correct'){
                         window.location='/';
                   } else {
                   }
          }
          });
        return true;
    }

    function trim(str){
         var str=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
         return str;
    }
    </script>

    <div class="login">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="memail" value="" placeholder="Email" class="memail">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" id="mpass" value="" placeholder="Password" class="mpassword">
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-submit-section">
            <div class="payment-submit">
                <div class="order-submit">
                    <button id="msubmit" type="submit" name="submit_button" class="greenx" style="margin-top:-20px;" onclick="validLogin()">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

and

    ------ processed.php ---------
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once('../db/ds.php');
    $message=array();
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $email= htmlentities($email);
    }else{
        $message[]='email';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
    $password= htmlentities($password);
    }else{
        $message[]='password';
    }
    $countError=count($message);
    if($countError > 0){
     for($i=0;$i<$countError;$i++){
     }
}else{
$password=md5($password);
$query = "select * from user where email='$email' and password='$password'";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$checkUser = $res->num_rows;
    if($checkUser > 0){
    $lol = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $iduser = $lol['id'];
    $_SESSION['status']=true;
    $_SESSION['id']=$iduser;
    echo 'correct';
    }else{
    }
}
}
?>
```

maybe this code for CSRF, but I do not know how to use them

```
function createToken()
{
    $token= base64_encode( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    $_SESSION['csrfvalue']=$token;
    return $token;  
}
function unsetToken()
{
    unset($_SESSION['csrfvalue']);
}
function validation()
{   
    $csrfvalue = isset($_SESSION['csrfvalue']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['csrfvalue']) : ''; 
    if(isset($_POST['csrf_name']))
    {       
        $value_input=$_POST['csrf_name'];

        if($value_input==$csrfvalue)
        {
            unsetToken();
            return true;            
        }else{
            unsetToken();
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        unsetToken();
        return false;
    }
}

<input type="hidden" name="csrf_name" value="<?php echo createToken();?>"/>
```

How to use CSRF without input `<form action="" method="post">`? Because when I test the security of this code, this code dangerous if not using CSRF. 
I've been looking for to several sites , but they all use input `form`.

1.How to use CSRF in the above code ?

2. Whether my code is too simple? and could be tricked ? How do I secure it ?
3. If i use ajax , Whether I have to use CSRF ?

> **EDIT**

**--------------- processed.php ----------------**

```
<?php
require '../../db/sessions.php';
require '../../db/ds.php';
require '../../db/error.php';
$user=$row['id'];
$message=array();

if(isset($_POST['emailx']) && !empty($_POST['emailx'])){
    $emailx = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['emailx']);
$emailx= htmlentities($emailx);
}else{
    $message[]='email';
}
if(isset($_POST['hpx']) && !empty($_POST['hpx'])){
    $hpx = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['hpx']); 
$hpx= htmlentities($hpx);
}else{
    $message[]='hp';
}
if(isset($_POST['namax']) && !empty($_POST['namax'])){
    $namax = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['namax']); 
    $namax= htmlentities($namax);
}else{
    $message[]='nama';
}
if(isset($_POST['token']) && !empty($_POST['token'])){
    $tokens = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['token']);
}else{
    $message[]='email';
}
$countError=count($message);

if($countError > 0){
     for($i=0;$i<$countError;$i++){
     }
}else{

    if(validation($tokens, $crsfa)==true) {
        $query = "UPDATE user SET email='$emailx', nama='$namax', hp='$hpx' WHERE id='$user'";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        echo 'OKS';
    }else{
        echo "Null";
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

**--------------- index.php ----------------**

```
<meta name="csrf_token" content="<?php echo createToken();?>">
.
.
.
.
.
<script>
function validUbah() {
      var hpx=$('#hp').val();
      var emailx=$('#email').val();
      var namax=$('#nama').val();
      var token=$('[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
      var dataString = 'hpx='+ hpx + '&emailx='+ emailx + '&namax='+ namax + '&token='+ token;
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "processed.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(result){
               var result=trim(result);
               if(result=='OKS'){
            $(".spinner").hide();
            $(".spanlogin").show();
            $(".spanlogin").html('Berhasil');
            $(".nm7").html(namax);
               } else {
            $(".spinner").hide();
            $(".spanlogin").show();
            $(".spanlogin").html(result);
        return false;
               }

      }
      });
    return true;
}
function trim(str){
     var str=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
     return str;
}
</script>
```

**`--------------- sessions.php ---------------------`**

```
function unsetToken()
{
    unset($crsfa);
    createToken();
}

function validation($varians, $crsfa)
{   
    $csrfvalue = isset($crsfa); 
    if(isset($varians))
    {       
        $value_input=$varians;

        if($value_input==$csrfvalue)
        {
            unsetToken();
            return true;            
        }else{
            unsetToken();
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        unsetToken();
        return false;
    }
}

    $crsfa=$_SESSION['csrfvalue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are implementing anti-CSRF techniques, you should use the token on every post/ajax request.

Maybe you can implement your token as meta-Tag:
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="MERvRHE0MmVHcSU9OEUfPHs3JSALZQpcAC1ccBVcZA14KVlxN35xHQ==">`

Whatever you do, do NOT use MD5 for hashing passwords.
Use PHP's crypt() or other means for password storage.

Cheers

Comment: my next question .csrf-token will be incorporated into mysql or what?if you look at the code above , how can I use it ? because if you use the code above, how to replace the following code `$csrfvalue = isset($_SESSION['csrfvalue']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['csrfvalue']) : ''; 
    if(isset($_POST['csrf_name']))` when using `meta` ?

Comment: Sorry ive edited, if you see **processed.php** i have this `if(validation($tokens, $crsfa)==true) {` and function validation in **session.php** `function validation($varians, $crsfa)` 
whether CSRF like it or not ?